# How can I change volume.number to volume(number) in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, citing

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

Read \textcite{sarfraz}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Reference list this creates:

> Sarfraz, M. and M. F. A. Razzak (2002). “Technical section: An algorithm for automatic capturing of the font outlines”. In: *Computers and Graphics* 26.5, pp. 795–804. issn: 0097-8493.

But the output I need is:

> Sarfraz, M. and M. F. A. Razzak (2002). “Technical section: An algorithm for automatic capturing of the font outlines”. In: *Computers and Graphics,* 26(5), pp. 795–804. issn: 0097-8493.

So instead of "*Computers and Graphics* 26.5,", I want "*Computers and Graphics,* 26(5),".

So I try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot\addcomma}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\begin{document}

Read \textcite{sarfraz}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Now I get:

> Sarfraz, M. and M. F. A. Razzak (2002). “Technical section: An algorithm for automatic capturing of the font outlines”. In: *Computers and Graphics,* 26.(5), pp. 795–804. issn: 0097-8493.

This is almost what I want except that I still need to get rid of the dot from "26.(5)". How can I change "26.(5)" to "26(5)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine the `volume+number+eid` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\bibeidpunct}%
  \printfield{eid}}


\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\begin{document}

Read \textcite{sarfraz,angenendt}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Or you could switch to a style from the `biblatex-ext` package. Then you could simply do `\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}` to remove the period:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\begin{document}

Read \textcite{sarfraz,angenendt}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding trailing punctuation in field formats as in `\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot\addcomma}}` is rarely a good idea as it bypasses `biblatex`'s punctuation buffer and relies on other bits of `biblatex`'s punctuation tracking to avoid double punctuation (which may not always work). With `biblatex-ext` you have `\jourvoldelim` available to modify the relevant punctuation command. With plain `biblatex` you have to redefine `journal+issuetitle` as well.

Comment: @moewe I removed this line as it is not directly related to the question.